# Filter Realtime Events

Tags: platform-event, event-monitoring

So we have realtime events and they are great but the issue we are having is very often we don't need the full "hosepipe" of events only events related to a specific record or user where based on some method they are marked as high risk. Is there any way to filter these events before they are sent to us as 99% of all of these events we have no interest in and are just dropping it seems wasteful.

Answer (score 3):

With winter 23 one can easily filter platform event by defining a filter expression via the metadata or the tooling API!

Check out the details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_filters.htm)

Read more about the General Availability of the [feature](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_platform_events_filtering_ga.htm&type=5&release=240).

Comment: Does this address the problem at hand, though?  Is there a way to configure a platform event filter so that it is dynamic, as in deliver only those events that relate to a specific record?

Comment: yeah this doesn't seem very dynamic each user will have very different interests and this seems to be only good for general fixed filtering.